# Why move semantics have the same behavior as shallow copy in dynamic mem allocation?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shallow-copy

In the classes dealing with dynamic mem allocation, shallow copy basically causes the program to delete a resource twice. In move operations, 
the original pointer no longer points to the resource, So But why the same behavior occurs in move semantics? e.g:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class MyString
{
    char* cstr;
 public:
    MyString(const char* arg)
    : cstr(new char[strlen(arg)+1])
    {
        strcpy(cstr, arg);
    }
    MyString(MyString&&) = default;
    MyString& operator=(MyString&&) = default;
    MyString(const MyString&) = delete;
    MyString& operator=(const MyString&) = delete;
    ~MyString()
    {
        delete[] cstr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyString S1{"aaa"};
    MyString S2 = move(S1); // error

}
```

I've tried with 3 different compilers and i got the same results.

Comment: You still have to null out the original pointer which the default move constructor doesn't do for you.

Comment: "the original pointer no longer points to the resource" - why? With raw pointers it is your responsibility to ensure that. And you are not ensuring it.

Comment: This is why committee members argued that `move` was misleading. It's a type-cast. It doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: If one of the compilers you used is Visual Studio, the debugger clearly shows what the issue is, i.e., the pointer was not "moved".  Also [read the first paragraph in the definition of std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).  Note the word *indicate*.

Comment: @AndyG std::move causes the move ctor to be called witch then makes memberwise move. I didn't get your point that "it doesn't actually do anything" it's causing the move ctor to be executed.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious If it's not causing the original pointer to be null, it's clearly not holding its original value either. That alone should prevent the double-destruction of a same memory.

Comment: Yes, it is holding its original value. What makes you think it's not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implicitly generated move constructor move-constructs each member. Your member is a pointer. Moving a pointer (or any other primitive object) is same as copying it.

So, since your move constructor does nothing else besides moves the pointer, the moved from `MyString` object will still be pointing to the same pointee object as the moved to `MyString` object. And when both are destroyed, the destructor will try to delete the pointee twice.

You need to follow the rule of 5: If any of destructor, move/copy constructor, move/copy assignment needs to be implemented, then all of them probably need to be implemented (or deleted). You've implemented the destructor to delete an owned pointer, so you must implement the move constructor (and the others) such that the moved from (or copied from) object no longer points to the object that it no longer owns.

> Why move semantics have the same behavior as shallow copy in dynamic mem allocation?

Because moving is just another word for shallow copying. The move constructor and assignment operator are there to be given a custom implementation in case the moved from object needs to be cleaned up to maintain the class invariant. Just like the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are there to make a deep copy that does not break the class invariant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but why "Moving a pointer (or any other primitive object) is same as copying it.",? I don't understand, then what's whole the point of std::move on lvalues? isn't it to "move" the values?

Comment: The point of std::move is to convert an lvalue to an rvalue. The point of the conversion is to allow copy initialization of another object by move.

Comment: and the move doesn't transfer/move the values?

Comment: @joghd This question might help: [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks  for the link. I already checked that out. The point that i still can't understand is that it seems `std::move` sometimes transfers its argument's value, sometimes it doesn't. The first case is what happened in my example. My conclusion is that, the values of `move`ed object may or may not be transfered; but if they don't, they are not stable/guaranteed. Have i understood it right?

Comment: @joghd: `std::move` does not provoke the actual movement of the object. What does the actual moving is the construction of the new object or assignment to an existing object from the *return value* of `std::move`. Furthermore, exactly what "move" means depends on the object(s) in question. An object which does not own resources will likely have "move" be no different from a "copy".

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you very much. That was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> [why is] Moving a pointer (or any other primitive object) is same as copying it.

Because in C++, you do not pay for what you do not use (in general).

A naked pointer (aka: not a smart pointer) in C++ is assumed to be non-owning with regard to the object it points to. This is why you *must* delete it manually; the compiler doesn't generate an implicit `delete` statement for any pointers that fall out of scope.

Since a pointer does not own memory, why is it correct to null out the source of a pointer when you move one? It isn't. It's perfectly valid for a non-owning pointer's move to just copy the pointer value and leave the old one. Just like it's perfectly valid for a non-owning pointer to be destroyed without destroying what it points to.

C++ doesn't know that you need to delete that pointer, just as it doesn't know you need to null out the old one. If you need that, then *you* have to do it.

If you want to create an owning pointer, it is you who must create those semantics. These semantics are more expensive than non-owning semantics. A pointer move is just a bitwise-copy; a smart-pointer move has to run actual code. It has to do two memory store operations: storing the old value in the new pointer, and nulling-out the old pointer. That's more expensive than one.

And therefore, you have to *explicitly* ask for it or do it yourself.

---

To understand the potential effect on performance, consider a `vector<T*>`. Now, let's consider that this type is a private member of a class. This class dynamically allocates some `T`s and puts them in the `vector`. It also ensures that any `T`s added are deleted when the class is deleted.

So, let's consider what `vector<T*>` would have to look like with your proposed idea of moving a pointer causing the old value to become `nullptr`. One important element of `vector` is reallocation; when you insert more elements than the `vector` can hold, it has to allocate larger storage and move all of the elements to the new storage, then delete the older storage.

With your proposed idea, reallocating a `vector<T*>` would mean moving all of the pointer elements. But each move is two memory operations: copying the value and nulling out the old one. But the thing is, the old value? That value is about to be *destroyed*. And the class that owns the `vector<T*>` doesn't need to delete it or anything; it will be in the new storage. So there is no reason why `vector<T*>` needed to null out a value that's going to be deleted.

By contrast, a modern `vector<T*>` implementation will "move" the pointers by doing a single `memcpy` of the entire buffer to the new location. It can do this because pointers are trivially-copyable, which allows them to be both copied and moved by doing byte-wise copies.

So your way is *much* slower. And your way gains nothing, because the old value will be dropped when the memory is deallocated. So there's no need to null it out in that case.

C++ doesn't know when you're implementing `vector` or implementing a smart pointer. Therefore, it goes for the lowest-common-denominator: pointers are trivially copyable. If you want specialized move behavior, you must implement it.